# SSH invocation of a subsystem SFTP using command line

Tags: ssh, sftp

I am facing a problem where I have an SFTP server (with no SSH shell access).

When from a client machine I do SFTP request it works:

```
sftp username@remote_IP
```

Then if I do a SSH request it hangs

```
ssh -l username -s remote_IP sftp
```

But the `ssh` man page suggest that

```
-s      May be used to request invocation of a subsystem on the remote
        system.  Subsystems facilitate the use of SSH as a secure
        transport for other applications (e.g. sftp(1)).  The subsystem
        is specified as the remote command.
```

Does SSH server at remote server must enable this or there is some other way out for this?

Adding verbose logs .... let me first share you the `sftp` verbose mode logs which suggests:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)
debug1: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug2: TCP receive buffer size: 49640 B
debug1: SSH receive window size: 198560 B
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug1: send channel open 0
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug1: ssh_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: channel request 0: subsystem
debug2: callback done
debug1: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug2: Remote version: 3
debug3: Sent message fd 5 T:16 I:1
debug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> /root
sftp> pwd
```

Now I am showing the verbose output of `ssh -l username -s remote_IP sftp`

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
```

This is where it hangs.

The problem in short is *"If SFTP works and is enabled on server what happens to `ssh` which is calling subsystem `sftp` on remote server"*? What exactly is required at server end or as a matter of fact at client side to make it work?

Please clarify my basic understanding, if I have understood something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you expect it to do?

It starts the SFTP server. And the server waits for SFTP requests, particularly for the `SSH_FXP_INIT`. And it never gets one. The SSH terminal (`ssh`) will hardly send an SFTP packet.

So it hangs. As expected.

---

*(Note that despite the same, the `SSH_FXP_INIT` is an SFTP request, not an SSH request. The `SSH_FXP` stands for something like "**SSH** **f**ile e**x**change **p**rotocol")*

---

You haven't really explained us what do you expect.

So let me guess.

You actually believe that the SFTP is a textual protocol. That the commands (like `rm`, `put`, etc) that you type in the `sftp` (OpenSSH command-line SFTP client) are real commands that go to the server. They are not. The SFTP is a binary protocol. Those commands are proprietary commands of one specific SFTP client implementation. The client (OpenSSH `sftp`) translates those textual commands to binary SFTP packets/requests and sends them to the server. And then it translates the binary responses from the SFTP server to human readable textual messages.

Those textual commands cannot be real exchange with the server even theoretically. Simple commands, like the `rm`, could. But what about the `put` or `get`? If you do `put /local/path`, how can the SFTP server access the local file to read it? It cannot. The SFTP client does that.

That's similar to FTP. The FTP is a textual protocol. You can theoretically talk to the FTP server by typing the commands. You can delete remote files this way for example (using `DELE /path/to/file` command). But you cannot upload or download files this way. That requires cooperation with the local FTP software.

> What exactly is required at server end or as a matter of fact at client side to make it work?

Your server-end works as expected. But you need an actual SFTP client on the client side.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for quick reply , in this particular case SSH_FXP_INIT is been sent by client. Means 1st SFTP packet is sent. It is receiving in the second message from server as well ( as seen in wireshark analysis of dump ) ... still client hangs

Comment: What client sends the `SSH_FXP_INIT`? Does not make sense. So show us the dump.

Comment: to elaborate more ... the client hangs at
 

debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp

debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1

debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY

debug2: callback done

debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768

debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0

debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0

Comment: That does not give us any information we do not know already. It shows no SFTP packet exchange.

Comment: In wireshark I can see the messages getting transferred between client and server ( showing sshv2 messages) : 

SSHv2 Client: Key Exchange Init
SSHv2 Server: Key Exchange Init
SSHv2 Client: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Init
SSHv2 Server: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply
SSHv2 Client: New Keys
SSHv2 Server: New Keys
SSHv2 Client: Encrypted Packet
SSHv2 Server: Encrypted Packet

Comment: But those are SSH packages, not SFTP packets. Where do you see the `SSH_FXP_INIT`?

Comment: I'm afraid you have some conceptual misunderstanding. But it's hard for us to guess what that is. It would really help, if you try to explain us, what are you trying to do. And what do you expect and why?

Comment: The problem in short is " If SFTP works and is enabled on server what happens to ssh which is calling subsystem stfp on remote server". What exactly is required at server end to make it work.

Comment: It's still not clear what you expect. But I've tried to guess. See my updated answer.