# Executing SFTP commands using Paramiko in Python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I want to connect to SFTP server and execute commands, like `ls`. But I'm getting an error:

> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to open channel.

```
import paramiko
import pysftp
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('xxxxxxxx', username='xxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxx', key_filename='xxxxxxxxxxx')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seem that you believe that your code executes SFTP `ls` command. It does not. It tries to execute `ls` **shell** command. Your server probably does not even allow executing shell commands, hence the error.

If you want to use SFTP, you need to use [`SFTPClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html) and its methods like [`SFTPClient.listdir`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir).

---

Note that SFTP protocol does not have textual commands like `ls`. SFTP is a binary protocol. The commands, that you know, are [commands of a common SFTP client – the OpenSSH `sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#INTERACTIVE_COMMANDS). The OpenSSH `sftp` maps user text commands to binary SFTP protocol requests. The same way Paramiko `SFTPClient` class maps calls to its methods to equivalent binary SFTP protocol requests.

For more details, see also my answer to [SSH invocation of a subsystem SFTP using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40042140/850848).

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my problem is as follow:

## how to read rsa key

```
    pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/Users/rajesh.maulekhi/Downloads/id_rsa')
```

## function resturn sftp client

```
def multifactor_auth_sftp_client(host, port, username, key, password):
#Create an SSH transport configured to the host
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
#Negotiate an SSH2 session
transport.connect()
#Attempt authenticating using a private key
transport.auth_publickey(username, key)
#Create an event for password auth
password_auth_event = threading.Event()
#Create password auth handler from transport
password_auth_handler = paramiko.auth_handler.AuthHandler(transport)
#Set transport auth_handler to password handler
transport.auth_handler = password_auth_handler
#Aquire lock on transport
transport.lock.acquire()
#Register the password auth event with handler
password_auth_handler.auth_event = password_auth_event
#Set the auth handler method to 'password'
password_auth_handler.auth_method = 'password'
#Set auth handler username
password_auth_handler.username = username
#Set auth handler password
password_auth_handler.password = password
#Create an SSH user auth message
userauth_message = paramiko.message.Message()
userauth_message.add_string('ssh-userauth')
userauth_message.rewind()
#Make the password auth attempt
password_auth_handler._parse_service_accept(userauth_message)
#Release lock on transport
transport.lock.release()
#Wait for password auth response
password_auth_handler.wait_for_response(password_auth_event)
#Create an open SFTP client channel
return transport.open_sftp_client()
```